# Getting undefined instead of a correct result

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrow-functions

I am trying to use forEach method on my array but I am getting undefined instead of a correct result. Could anyone help me and tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
[0,1,2,3].forEach((x,i) => (x*i)%3);
```

Answer (score 3):

The return value of `forEach()` is `undefined`, use [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead:

```js
var r = [0,1,2,3].map((x,i) => (x*i)%3);
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which doesn't return anything, so the result of calling it is `undefined`. (`forEach` also  completely ignores the return value of the callback it calls.)

If you want a return value, you probably want [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (or possibly [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)), not `forEach`. For example:

```js
console.log([0,1,2,3].map((x,i) => (x*i)%3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning nothing inside the forEach, write a console.log for that

Answer (score 1):

This is from https://developer.mozilla.org/

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the end of a chain.

If you are trying to transform the array, use map() instead